# MS Access Click Letter to Filter Report

Tags: ms-access, report

I'm trying to find a sample database that use to be included with MS Access (I think) that was like a phone book, what I am specifically interested in was a report/form where you have the buttons A-Z running across the top and then the names listed below and if you clicked 'A' you would only see those names with surnames starting in A and so on. Does anyone know what that template database is called (using Access 2010) or how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you Googled for it? Also, I never used that template, but probably you can reply it with some VBA code, aplying filters if a button is selected (example: If you press button of letter A, filter records starting with A)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I have tried to google it but no come up with it. I was hoping to see how that worked rather than re-inventing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this is to create the command button cmd_A, and give it a Caption "A".

In the properties dialog, I would enter the following in the OnClick event:

```
On Click: =FilterMyForm()
```

Then I would create the function in the code behind the function:

```
Private Function FilterMyForm()

    Dim strFilter as string

    strFilter = "[FieldName] Like '" & screen.ActiveControl.Caption & "*'"
    me.filter = strFilter
    me.FilterON = true

End Sub
```

Then I would copy this button to get your 26 letters and change the caption of each button as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is small example created by me: [Access DB Contact List with alphabet links](https://ufile.io/gtr21)